# Update object which has used builder method in Java8 using Lombok

Tags: java-8, lombok

Hi I'm having the following piece of code

```
        BBResponse bbStmtResponse = BBResponse.builder().result(IN_PROGRESS).build();
```

After few validations, I want to update the object "bbStmtResponse" to set to other properties as

```
bbStmtResponse.builder().status(SUCCESS).build();
```

When  I print the bbStmtResponse object, it doesn't hold "result" property value which was supposed to be"IN_PROGRESS". How can I overcome this, instead of using setter methods as there are more properties to set

Comment: it looks like you would need to take a "previous" instance in the `builder` method - if you understand what Builder pattern does, then it would be a lot easier for you. There is not much to "overcome" - when you call `builder()` - you initiate a new Object creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

- Use `toBuilder` method

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public BBResponse
```

Then use `bbStmtResponse.toBuilder().status(SUCCESS)`

- Use `@Setter` to enable both builder and setter:

```
@Setter
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public BBResponse
```